# how make oauth 2.0 works in my web application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing a small web application and am blocked at the step to make an authentication for users , to be more clear I Followed the steps to configure the OAUTH 2.0 in the credentials option  and when I tape my URL application in the Browser the authentication window does not appear at the website ,so is what I did good enough or I have to do something other in the code side at eclipse.

Comment: Can you provide a code so we can know what are you doing exactly ?

Comment: Its a webapplication and I need make an authentication option to let users acces to the website , as I said befor I followed the steps to configure the Oauth 2.0 in credentials options , so I ask if do I to provide a code in eclipse too and how ? thanks

Comment: Did you already authenticated once to your app? If so, it is normal the pop-up authentication does not open anymore since you are already authentified. As User555 said, it would be good to have your code to see where is the problem, or at least the URL of the page from where you got the documentation.

Comment: I did not authenticated yet to my app , thats the url where I got the configuration : https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en

Comment: That 's why I asked If I Need to tape a code at eclipse side

Comment: Note : I deployed the application to appenigne and put the URL in that configuration credentials

Comment: Hope there is some one understand my situation ,thanks